# Удаленный компьютер не пингуется

Tags: виртуальная-машина, ubuntu

Удаленный комп - Ubuntu в виртуалке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А он и не должен пинговаться! Он же, как минимим, за NAT-ом, и напрямую в сеть не выходит.

Хотя, смотря какая виртуалка... В Hyper-V, например, если "external" на рабочем порту включить, то перехватывать будет.

Comment: vmware. А что можно сделать? Что и по ssh теперь не подключиться?

Comment: Проброс портов погугли.

Comment: И ещё - я неправильно несколько ответил. Не на раюочем порту, а на рабочем интерфейсе.

Answer (score 1):

Вот был похожий вопрос [Настройка соединения по сети](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/4936/linux-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8), точнее ответ по виртуалкам вполне общий и, думаю, всё расставит на свои места.

Answer (score 1):

Товарищ поставь на стройках виртуалки соединение типа: "Мост" aka Bridge. Далее на Ubuntu настрой под сеть такую же как основная  ну если есть dhcp сервер то как вариант dhclient ethX (где Х-номер сетевухи)

Comment: Уж если мост - то на хосте! С виртуальной от ВМВари.

Comment: ну на самой виртале будь то Vbox или WMW то полюбому настраиваться на хосте те в самой программе

Answer (score 1):

Все гораздо проще,В случае c "**VM VirtualBox**" для сетевого адаптера в виртуальной машине выбирается тип адаптера : "Виртуальный адаптер хоста".

```
Машина - Свойства - Сеть - Тип подключения - "Виртуальный адаптер хоста".
```

После чего виртуальная машина может пинговаться из хоста.(две виртуальные машины также будут пинговаться между собой при таком выборе сетевых адаптеров).